# I get this error code while doing some openCV work

Tags: python

This is what shows as the output:

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed ((scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == 0 
|| depth == 5)) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11214
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "set_hand_hist.py", line 70, in <module>
get_hand_hist()
File "set_hand_hist.py", line 38, in get_hand_hist
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11214: error: (-215) (scn == 3 || 
scn == 4) && (depth == 0 || depth == 5) in function cv::cvtColor
```

Comment: Could you post your codes here?

Comment: You need to post code and error, we don’t know what you try to do and “debugging of the code” does imply the actual code.

Comment: if keypress == ord('c'):  
   hsvCrop = cv2.cvtColor(imgCrop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   flagPressedC = True
   hist = cv2.calcHist([hsvCrop], [0, 1], None, [180, 256], [0, 180, 0, 256])
   cv2.normalize(hist, hist, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your image might have 4 color channels instead of 3, like RGBA instead of RGB. You can load it specifically to have 3 color channels with

```
img = cv2.IMREAD_COLOR('path/to/img')
```

Note that this loads in BGR, so then you can convert using:

```
cv2.cvtcolor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Comment: you can double check the number of channels using 

    num_channels = np.shape(img)[2]